# Put results in different divs depending on what comes out of the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, backend

**How it looks:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jef2L8m6/

**How it should look:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jef2L8m6/1/

I know it looks really bad, this is just for testing purposes only.

**Some of the Backend Code:**

```
<?php //Selects all of the logged in users messages.
$name = $_SESSION["name"];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','chat');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY date";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if( $numrows == "0" or !isset($_SESSION["name"])){
           echo "<div class='msg'>You are not registered (Or there are no messages to display)</div>";
           exit();
      }else{
           echo "";
      }


echo "<div class='msg_container'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='msg_user'>";
    echo "<div class='username_user'><span>" . $row['username'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "<div class='message_user'><span>" . $row['message'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
echo "";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thank you so much for taking your time to read this.

I am trying to figure out how I would change the div tags of each separate user depending on their name?

Is there any way to do this using PHP, I have tried doing 2 separate query's of one that selects just the users messages and another that selects everyones (excluding the users)

But none of them worked due to it not ordering them correctly.

Could I somehow change the div's using PHP if the username that comes out is not equal to the username in the session?

**Thank's so much, if you don't think I explained this very well please give me some feedback and I will change/add what you need, THANK YOU!**

Comment: So what is the problem with comparing `$row['username']` and session value?

Comment: Just check the logged in user session with the userId, and put his messages in right and others in left

Comment: Why dont you set the local user `$name` and the user from database to toggle the `class` with an `if ... else ` to switch the sides.

Comment: How exactly would I do this?

How would I get the div class to change if the username is equal to the session that has been set, otherwise the class should stay the same?

Comment: @u_mulder If I compared the row username and the session value, how would I be able to change the div class for only the person who has their session set to their name?

The user who is logged in should have their div class to be msg_user and everyone else should be set to msg, this is the same for the username div etc as you can see on the JSFiddle.

Comment: if username is the same as session - use one class, else - use another class. Isn't it?

Comment: @u_mulder How would I tell it to use one class else use another class buddy?

I think I kind of get what you mean, but how would I put it into practice? If you have an idea on how you would code this using the code I already have I would be very grateful if you posted an answer and I will try it out!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image of the system now working.]

Thank you so much "u_mulder", you have been very helpful in making me think of a simple way to solve this problem.

I was thinking way too complex for something so simple!

**Here is the final code for anyone who this may help:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $class_msg = "msg";
    $class_username = "username";
    $class_message = "message";

    if ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['name']) {
    $class_msg = "msg_user";
    $class_username = "username_user";
    $class_message = "message_user";
    }

    echo "<div class='$class_msg'>";
    echo "<div class='$class_username'><span>" . $row['username'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "<div class='$class_message'><span>" . $row['message'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $class = 'msg';
    if ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['name']) {
        $class = 'msg_user';
    }

    echo "<div class='" . $class . "'>";
    // other codes here
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: I will try this out, I understand the logic, there must of been a reason I didn't try something like this.

I will let you know what happens.

Comment: @Zabuza

It's not too complicated, it checks if the row that is outputted from the database is equal to the string inside the session.

It then changes the div based on whether the session equals the name.

Hopefully it works I am going to test it out (I don't know why I didn't think of this)

Comment: @Zabuza My brain was going to like a str_replace type function, I don't know why I didn't think of the simple to start with!

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you very much, your solution was very helpful!

It's now working without fault.